# Nullpointer Exception при попытке создать SimpleXsdSchema

Tags: spring-mvc, xsd

Собственно суть в том, что есть некий проект на spring MVC, где для soap сервиса нужно создать wsdl на основе xsd схемы, но при инициализации приложения и конкретно класса  SimpleXsdSchema падёт НПЕ.(отловлено в дебаггере):

```html
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.toString()
```

Код на создание: 
       SimpleXsdSchema   simpleXsdSchema = new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/user.xsd"));

Пробовал создать просто класс с методом main и просто сделать так:

```
       SimpleXsdSchema simpleXsdSchema = new SimpleXsdSchema();
   simpleXsdSchema.setXsd(new ClassPathResource("xsd/user.xsd"));
   System.out.println(simpleXsdSchema);
```

ошибка:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.getTargetNamespace(SimpleXsdSchema.java:94) at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.toString(SimpleXsdSchema.java:134) at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821) at com.epam.beans.App.main(App.java:21)
```

Ок, я думал, что дело в том, что targetNameSapce кривой, но скачав просто тестовый проект отсюда:

[тестовый проект](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-soap-web-service-producer-consumer-example-with-tomcat)
 и попытавшись его запустить, я получил тот же результат, ошибка валится, а в томкатовской консоли идёт:

```
30-Jul-2017 11:54:25.487 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.DefaultMessagesProvider.addMessages No messages were created, make sure the referenced schema(s) contain elements
30-Jul-2017 11:54:25.488 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider.createOperations No operations were created, make sure the WSDL contains messages
```

Схема xsd, которую я в своём проекте пытаюсь распарсить:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/user-web-service">

  <xs:element name="user" type="User" />

  <xs:complexType name="User">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <![CDATA[Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
User: name
Date: 2/1/2016
Time: 7:35 PM]]>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="birthday" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userRole" type="userRole" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="userRole">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="REGISTERED_USER" />
      <xs:enumeration value="BOOKING_MANAGER" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Путь к нему правильный, я кстати пробовал просто убирать targetNamespace из схемы и тогда валилась ошибка, что targetNamespace отсуствует в схеме, то есть в сам файл я так понял проект лезет, но результата никакого.

Answer (score 0):

В общем всё оказалось банальнее, чем я думал, нужно было именно нагенерить сначала классы через jaxb2-maven-plugin - xjs, чтобы получились целые сервисы, а я на генерил только саму схему xsd через schemagen